# Doubt in change of variable in multiple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Suppose T is a $1-1$ ($\mathcal{C'}$ mapping of an open set $E \subset R^k$ into $R^k$
> such that $J_{T(x)} \ne 0$ for all $x \in E$. If $f$ is a continuous function on $R^k$ whose support is compact and lies in $T(E)$, then
>
> $\int_{R^k}f(y)dy = \int_{R^k}f(T(x))|J_T(x)|dx$

This is the generalization of the change of variables in the one-dimensional case.

In one dimensional case we have
$\int_{R^1}f(y) dy = \int_{R^1}f(T(x))T'(x) dx$,

So if we try to generalize this then $T'(x)$ becomes a $k \times k$ matrix .What I don't understand is that why are we taking the determinant of the function $T'(x)$?Is it solely because $T'(x)$ is a $k \times k$ matrix which cannot be multiplies with $f(T(y))$ to get a scalar or is there an intuition behind this?

Comment: The absolute value of the determinant exactly gives the volume of the image of the unit cube under a linear transformation. This times $\epsilon^k$ is approximately the volume of the image of $T$ on a cube with side lengths $\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit. I don't think there is much about this in Rudin..

Comment: If you don't have a good feel for it, try integrating 1 on the unit ball with $T(x)=cx$ for various scalar values of $c$. You should find that the domain of integration is $|c|^k$ times smaller than it originally was so you need to go back and multiply by $|c|^k$ to correct for that, which is the formula with the determinant achieves. In the general situation you are taking into account the variation in how small volume elements near each point are distorted by $T$.